# Conditioning on NumPy array based on values from different arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have two (sample) arrays in the following manner:

```
a = np.array([4, 5,-1, 2, -3, 3, -4])
b = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Now, I want to calculate the count of occurrences where (a > 0 and b == 0) and also where (a < 0 and b == 1). How can I condition an array based on values of two different arrays? If I try this:

```
a[a < 0 and b == 1]
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I can do it using loops, but I want to avoid it and see if there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can use the bitwise-and operator `&`. Take care to wrap the expressions in parentheses because `&` binds more tightly

```py
a[(a < 0) & (b == 1)]
```

One can achieve the same behavior with [`numpy.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html).

```py
mask = np.logical_and(a < 0, b == 1)
a[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. The problem was in fact being caused by the absence of the parentheses around each condition.